# RegEx for matching and extracting integers from a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Given strings in the format:

```
string_1 <- "s homo_sapiens.1            11858        281 +  248956422 TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"

string_2 <- "s mus_musculus.6         28206485        223 -  149736546 TTTTCTGTCTGCTAATTTGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTA----------------TTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT"
```

I need to extract the following elements: the integer following the "." (ie "1", and "6"; the first integer (ie "11858" and "28206485"); the second integer (ie "281" and "223"); the "+" or the "-"; the third integer (ie "248956422" and "149736546"); and the final sequence of characters.

I can extract the integer following the ".":

```
library(stringr)

chr <- str_split(string_1, "[.]")[[1]][2]
chr <- substr(chr, start = 1, stop = 2)
chr <- gsub(" ", "", chr)
```

I can extract the first integer:

```
start <- str_extract(string_1, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=\\s)")
```

I can extract the "+" or "-":

```
strand <- str_extract(string_1, "(?<=\\s)[+-](?=\\s)")
```

And I can extract the final sequence of characters:

```
seq <- str_extract(string_1, "[\\w\\-]+(?=\\s*)$")
```

However, I cannot figure out how to extract the others. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
str_match(string_1, "\\.(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([-+])\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(.*)")
     [,2]    [,3]  [,4][,5]  [,6]          [,7]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[1,] "1"  "11858" "281" "+"  "248956422"   "TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKl0lC/1) and its graph:

[image]

A simpler approach might be 1) removing the text up to the first dot including it (using a `^[^.]*\.` regex with `sub`) and then 2) splitting with 1+ whitespaces (using a simple `\s+` regex):

```
data <- sub("^[^.]*\\.", "", string_1)
strsplit(data, "\\s+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# [2] "11858"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# [3] "281"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# [4] "+"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# [5] "248956422"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# [6] "TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean aside from usig regex to get the groups you want from a line were all lines are formatted the same.

You could get all 5 groups with something line this:

```
/^(?:[\w\s_]+)\.(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s([+-](?:\s+)\d+)\s+([\w-]+)$/gm
```

For group 4 you'd have the + or - then a space then the number

a helpful resource is https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

For extracting the final sequence of characters, you can just use `\S+$` as the last sequence of characters continues as non-space characters till end of string.

**[Check this Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgVwqH/1)**

Also, if you want you can use this pattern to grab all your data using multiple groups,

```
\.(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*([-+])\s*(\d+)\s+(.*)
```

**[Regex Demo with all groups](https://regex101.com/r/bgVwqH/2)**

**[R Code Demo](https://rextester.com/SCSU85783)**

```
library(stringr)

s <- "s homo_sapiens.1            11858        281 +  248956422 TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"
str_match(s, pattern = "\\.(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*([-+])\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(.*)")
```

Output,

```
[[1]]
     [,1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[1,] ".1            11858        281 +  248956422 TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"
     [,2] [,3]    [,4]  [,5] [,6]       
[1,] "1"  "11858" "281" "+"  "248956422"
     [,7]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[1,] "TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete walkthrough in base `R`:

```
strings <- c("s homo_sapiens.1            11858        281 +  248956422 TTTTCTTTTCGTTAACTTGCCGTCAGCCTTTTCTTTGACCTCTTCTTTCTGTTCATGTGTATTTGCTGTCTCTTAGCCCAGACTTCCCGTGTCCTTTCCACCGGGCCTTTGAGAGGTCACAGGGTCTTGATGCTGTGGTCTTCATCTGCAGGTGTCTGACTTCCAGCAACTGCTGGCCTGTGCCAGGGTGCAAGCTGAGCACTGGAGTGGAGTTTTCCTGTGGAGAGGAGCCATGCCTAGAGTGGGATGGGCCAT-TGTTCATCTTCTGGCCCCTGTTGTCT",
             "s mus_musculus.6         28206485        223 -  149736546 TTTTCTGTCTGCTAATTTGCCACCAGTCATTTCCTA----------------TTACGTGTGTCTGCTGCCTCCTAGCCCAGGCT-----TGCCCTTCCTCCC--TCTTCTGAGGTGTCATAGGGTCGTGAC--------------------TTACCTGGTTTGGGGGAGTAGTTGG---------------AAGCTGAGTGA-GTGGTGGGGTTTTCTTATGCTAAAGACCTGCGTCCAGTATAGGAAGAGCCATGTGCCTCCACTCTGGCCCTTGTGGTCT")


pattern <- "^[^.]+\\.(?P<first>\\d)\\s+(?P<int1>\\d+)\\s+(?P<int2>\\d+)\\s+(?P<plusminus>[-+])\\s+(?P<int3>\\d+)\\s+(?P<rest>.+)"
(lst_ <- regmatches(strings, regexec(pattern, strings, perl = T)))

(df <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst_)),
                c("garbage", "first", "int1", "int2", "plusminus", "int3", "rest")))
df$garbage <- NULL
df
```

This yields (shortened)

```
  first     int1 int2 plusminus      int3
1     1    11858  281         + 248956422
2     6 28206485  223         - 149736546
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ob6SD2/1).